# SAS: how to combine color gradient scales in a single heatmap?

Tags: colors, sas, gradient, heatmap

I have one variable with two groups. I'm trying to produce a heatmap composed of two color gradient scales, with red for group n°1 and grey for group n°2. How can I use the proc template to specify the color gradient to each group?
I don't know if it is possible to do.

It is possible with discrete variables using proc template. But with continous variables and using a color gradient, is it possible?

Here are a sample of my data:

```
item resp percent group
1     1     16     1
1     2     35     1
1     3     35     1
1     4     12     1
2     1     12     1
2     2     39     1
2     3     27     1
2     4     22     1
3     1     12     2
3     2     39     2
3     3     27     2
3     4     22     2
4     1     55     2
4     2     39     2
4     3     6      2
4     4     0      2

proc template;
define statgraph heatmap;
    begingraph;
      rangeattrmap name="rmap";
        range 0 - 100 / rangecolormodel=(white blue);
      endrangeattrmap;
      rangeattrvar attrmap="rmap" var=newpct attrvar=pColor;
      layout overlay / yaxisopts=(display=(ticks tickvalues line))  ;
        heatmapparm x=resp y=item colorresponse=pColor / 
                          name="heatmap";
        continuouslegend "heatmap";
      endlayout;
    endgraph;
  end;
run;

proc sgrender data=freqall template=heatmap; 
run;
```

For now, my code only use one color. An idea to have two color gradients?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by two color gradients. Your are basically "heatmapping" the variable percent (BTW, the code you presented refers to a variable called newpct which I assume is the same as percent?) on a plot of item vs resp. So you can just just one gradient to represent that one variable. Not sure how multiple gradients can be used to represent 1 variable. Can you clarify please? Or do you want to use more than 2 colors in the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because group=2 items are 3 and 4, and do not overlap group=1 items 1 and 2, you can remap the percent data in the second group to a second adjacent range.  Add that adjacent range to your rangeattrmap.

Example:

```
data have; input
item resp percent group; datalines;
1     1     16     1
1     2     35     1
1     3     35     1
1     4     12     1
2     1     12     1
2     2     39     1
2     3     27     1
2     4     22     1
3     1     12     2
3     2     39     2
3     3     27     2
3     4     22     2
4     1     55     2
4     2     39     2
4     3     6      2
4     4     0      2

proc template;
  define statgraph heatmap;
    begingraph;
      rangeattrmap name="rmap";
        range   0 - <100 / rangecolormodel=(white red);
        range 100 - <200 / rangecolormodel=(green white);
      endrangeattrmap;
      rangeattrvar attrmap="rmap" var=percent attrvar=pColor;
      layout overlay / yaxisopts=(display=(ticks tickvalues line))  ;
        heatmapparm x=resp y=item colorresponse=pColor / 
                          name="heatmap";
        continuouslegend "heatmap";
      endlayout;
    endgraph;
  end;
run;

data have_map;
  set have;
  if percent = 100 then percent = 99.99;
  if group = 2 then percent = percent + 100;
run;

proc sgrender data=have_map template=heatmap; 
run;
```

[image]